# Regex: Match only person names?

Tags: regex

i'm not very good with regex, but I would like to match only a persons name.
Thus, each word would need to include atleast one vowel and such to be valid.

And I also want to leave out weird characters like <>()[] and such. What I got so far is something like this:

```
([^<>\(\)\[\]\\\/@].+)
```

Which should match something like this:

`John Johnson`

I have no idea how to check if there's a vowel in each word.

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for this.

Comment: @VisionarySoftwareSolutions Probably meant vowel.

Comment: I don't think regex is the right tool for this. try to extract name in this string: `"Hello John How Are You, Would You Marry Me?"`

Comment: I feel bad for John Johnson's son, John Johnson Jr. - he doesn't have a "valid" name according to you

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ I'd argue that John Johnson already is a junior...surely "Johnson" indicates that he is a "son of John" :-P

Comment: If you wanna get technical, the Regex provided will actually match ANY string of two or more characters, as long as the first character matches the regex `[^<>()[\]\\/@]` -- even something as horrible as `^blah~!@#$%^&*()_+`...

Answer (score 3):

Validating a person's name is usually only as good as validating they supplied one. Trying to ensure it is a *real* name is never a good idea, because someone will always have a name with a different rule.

1. Make separate fields for first, last, and middle initial.
2. If you want, validate they don't have numbers in there. Most people use Roman Numerals of they are indicating they are a "III" or "IV". I usually don't bother to do this.

Other than that, don't validate anymore. Why?

1. You will frustrate or upset potential users. The transliterated Cantonese last name [Ng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ng) is very popular, and lacks any vowels.
2. Names are being invented all the time.
3. How will your validation handle other character sets, like Cyrillic? What if a user wanted to use those in their name?

Answer (score 0):

As inadvisable as it is to try and validate a name (for reasons already mentioned and more!), the following regex should do what you want (series of letters and spaces with at least ONE vowel):

```
(?=\b[a-zA-Z ]*?[aeiouAEIOU][a-zA-Z ]*\b)\b[a-zA-Z ]*\b
```

I could break it down for you, but I can't recommend using it :D